# How to stop a video playing in background on next function where video is inserted via summernote

Tags: javascript

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
           var youTubeUrl = $('.note-video-clip').attr('src');
        $('#stop-video').click(function () {
            $('.note-video-clip').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('src', '');
                $('.note-video-clip').attr('src', youTubeUrl);
            });
        });
        });
```

Im using the above script to solve the issue, however its working only for the first page but not the second page on next function

Answer (score 0):

by using the below code we were able to solve the issue

```
 allNextChapter.click(function () {
                var sectionkey = $(this).attr("data-section");
                var chapterkey = $(this).attr("data-chapter");
                var youTubeUrl = $('.note-video-clip').attr('src');
            $("#stop-videoSection" + sectionkey + "Chapter" + chapterkey).find('.note-video-clip').attr('src', '');
            $('.note-video-clip').attr('src', youTubeUrl);
              
            });
```